# Run-Time Check Failure #2

Tags: c++

I have problem with such error: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'numb' was corrupted.
It appears at the last bracket of such function:

```
int problem20()
{
    int res = 0, i;
    int numb[160];
    for(i = 0; i < 160; i++)
        numb[i] = 0;
    numb[0] = 1;
    for(i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        multiply(numb, i, numb, 160);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 160; i++)
        res += numb[i];
    return res;
}
```

EDIT:

```
void multiply(int* a1, int a2, int* res, int l)
{
    int temp, i, m = a2, k;
    for(k = 0; m > 0; k++)
        m /= 10;
    int *result = new int[l + k];

    for(i = 0, temp = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        result[i] = a1[i] * a2 + temp;
        temp = result[i] / 10;
        result[i] %= 10;
    }
    for(i = l; i < l + k; i++)
    {
        result[i] = temp % 10;
        temp /= 10;
    }
    memcpy(res, result, sizeof(int) * (l + k));
    delete[] result;
}
```

function miltiply just multiply numb by i and give result to the third argument. This function is ok, it was tested earlier.

Comment: Please include the source to `multiply()`

Comment: probably `(l + k)` is greater than 160.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Problem was in memcpy and l + k, thanks.

Comment: You can not do: `memcpy(res, result, sizeof(int) * (l + k));` Your static array is only big enough for: `memcpy(res, result, sizeof(int) * l);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you pass numb as the res argument for the multiply function. The multiply function creates an array that has size l + k and then tries to copy it to the numb array with size l, this means that you are going out of the bounds of the numb array which in turn triggers this problem.

I would suggest turning the int* arguments to references to std::vector in order to avoid the need to manually allocate a temporary array.